# Java web app stops working after some time

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, glassfish

When I run my Java Web App, made using Netbeans, it runs perfectly with no problems, and everything seems to work, but if I leave it be, after some idle time, if wanted to do anything with it (mostly loading rows from database, jquery, ajax), nothing happens, when I refresh the page, I get this error.

[image]

I'm sorry because I couldn't post the log here, it was too big and my browser crashed every time I pasted, and when it worked Stackoverflow has a limit...so I uploaded it and here's the link.

http://www.crocko.com/99F6AEF8373B425A885BD379686EF2C5/server.log_2012-08-11T05-03-18

```
StandardWrapperValve[JoinPart]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet JoinPart threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at JoinPart.doGet(JoinPart.java:315)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770
```

EDIT: the current project was a copy of a previous project that contained a servlet `JoinPart.java`, after creating this copy, I deleted this servlet because I no longer needed it, I don't know if it still exist in some traces of this project, how can I get rid of it? this servlet is already deleted, I checked the javascript files, and none of them contains ajax requests on this servlet, I should have created a whole new project instead of copying, how can I get rid of any traces of this servlet?

Comment: Could you provice us with the full stack trace? (For how to get it, see the 'note' at the bottom of your image)

Comment: The stack trace so provided is referring to **NumberFormatException** and showing nothing about **NullPointerException** :-) Please try to paste the stack trace on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: I put the exception from your log in your post. Anyway it looks like you have a problem in JoinPart.doGet. If you post that method then someone might be able to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never copy projects if you intend to work on something completely different, always create new projects!

Answer (score 1):

Given the symptom and the very little information, I would guess that you are using something from the session.  Leaving it for a time you timeout.  Since you timed out on your next request you get a new session and it isn't setup the way you expect it to be anymore.  You reference something in the session and it's null and you aren't checking for that situation.  The stack trace should tell you where you are referencing that something.

Of course, this is just conjecture.  When you give more information you will get better answers.

Comment: See Preston's comment.  We need to know what is in JoinPart.  Line 315, with context (should be within the doGet method) would be especially helpful.

Comment: is the servlet mapped in web.xml? Does the class file exist in your jar file?